# I have added ionic on a cca (chrome for apps) project

Tags: google-chrome, cordova, ionic-framework, chrome-for-android

When i import the ionic files to cca: 3 errors

1º Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://oahcogjmifbbfieiciihfknbelknkojd/cordova.js

2º Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

3ºCan't open same-window link to "unsafe:chrome-extension://oahcogjmifbbfieiciihfknbelknkojd/index.html#/tab/friend/2"; try target="_blank".

Answer (score 2):

I can answer two of this

1° with cca you don't have to manually import cordova.js. So you can delete it from your index.html

3° this is angular.
let's put this on config of your module

```
 $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension):/);
```

Comment: What a life-saver this was.  Too bad it wasn't in any obvious part of any ionic or cca documentation.